# Angular changing object in scope doesn't change view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax, angularjs-scope

**Screencast:** http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDjX00isoo
**All Javascript:** http://fontget.com/js/all.js (at the bottom)
**Demo of the issue:** http://www.fontget.com

So I have this issue that I have been dealing with for a bit and can't seem to be able to figure it out. I am trying to give users the option of sorting the results from the database by clicking on a radio button with the specific filter.

When I click on the radio button I can see in the console that the correct url is grabbed using AJAX but the list is not getting updated in the view.

The page works when it is loaded for the first time (no sort filters).

**The controller:**

```
FontGet.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'FontService', '$location', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', function($scope, FontService, $location, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
    $rootScope.hideFatMenu = false;
    $scope.navCollapsed = true;
    $scope.isSettingsCollapsed = true;
    $rootScope.header = "Welcome to FontGet.com!";
    $scope.sortBy = 'new';

    $scope.fonts = {
        total: 0,
        per_page: 10,
        current_page: ((typeof($routeParams.page) !== 'undefined') ? $routeParams.page : 1),
        loading: true
    };

    $scope.setPage = function() {
        FontService.call('fonts', { page: $scope.fonts.current_page, sort: $scope.sortBy }).then( function(data) {
            $scope.fonts = data.data;
            $scope.fonts.loading = false;

            document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        });
    };


    $scope.$watch("sortBy", function(value) {
        $scope.setPage();
    });

    $scope.$watch("searchQuery", function(value) {
        if (value) {
            $location.path("/search/" + value);
        }
    });


    $scope.categories = FontService.categories();
    $scope.setPage();
}]);
```

**The View:**

```
<div class="fontdd" ng-repeat="font in fonts.data" >
    <!-- Stuff goes here. This is populated correctly when page initially loads -->
</div>
```

**The sort buttons:**

```
<ul class="radiobtns">
    <li>
        <div class="radio-btn">
            <input type="radio" value="value-1" id="rc1" name="rc1" ng-model="sorts" ng-change="sortBy = 'popular'">
            <label for="rc1" >Popularity</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="radio-btn">
            <input type="radio" value="value-2" id="rc2" name="rc1" ng-model="sorts" ng-change="sortBy = 'trending'">
            <label for="rc2">Trending</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="radio-btn">
            <input type="radio" value="value-4" id="rc4" name="rc1" checked="checked" ng-model="sorts" ng-change="sortBy = 'new'">
            <label for="rc4">Newest</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="radio-btn">
            <input type="radio" value="value-3" id="rc3" name="rc1" ng-model="sorts" ng-change="sortBy = 'alphabetical'">
            <label for="rc3">Alphabetical</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You will notice that the `ng-model` for the radio buttons is not set to `sortBy`. The reason for this is that if I set it to `sortBy` the AJAX call is made 4 times (no clue why thi is happening).

Comment: Quick answer to part of your question, anytime you use a `scope.$watch`, it'll get fired more often than you'd expect.  To filter out just the watch events that you really want, add something like this in the watch function:   `if (newVal == null || newVal===oldVal) return;`

Comment: @Dr.Cool `data.data` contains the correct data. `setPage` works just fine on the initial page load. The view doesn't change any time the data is changed by clicking the radio button.

Comment: @MeisamMulla, would be better if you could provide a demo that reproduces the issue.. by the way, why don't you create an array of `objects` to display these radio buttons (using `ngRepeat`) and simplify the things?

Comment: Yeah, a plunker would help and in the process of creating it you might discover what's wrong just by having to port it (and trim it down) into plunker.

Comment: @Dr.Cool Here is a screencast of it http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDjX00isoo I'm going to publish the changes I have made so that you guys can see it

Comment: In your `FontService.call().then()` function, can you add a `console.log(data.data)` and show us what it says?  I suspect there's something going on that part of the code.

Comment: @Dr.Cool It's outputting the exact same information just in a different order. I am including a file using `ng-include` would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `$scope.$watch` function to watch for changes in the `sortBy` scope variable.  You should try removing the watch and change your sort buttons' `ng-change` event to this:

```
    <div class="radio-btn">
        <input type="radio" value="value-1" id="rc1" name="rc1" ng-model="sorts" ng-change="Sort('popular')">
        <label for="rc1" >Popularity</label>
    </div>
```

In your controller, create a `Sort()` function:

```
$scope.Sort = function(sortBy) {
   $scope.sortBy = sortBy;
   $scope.setPage();
}
```

You don't really need to use `$watch` when you can just call a function and pass in the appropriate information.

Comment: It's still doing the same thing. The content is loaded correctly from what I can see in the console and `$scope.fonts` is updated as well but the view doesn't update.

Comment: @Dr.Cool, well, I agree that the use of `ngChange` is better than the use of `$watch`, however it doesn't change absolutely nothing in **this** case.

Comment: @developer033 The full javascript is at http://fontget.com/js/all.js (at the bottom) and the site is at http://fontget.com